# Converting a string to a JavaScript object - is there a safer way than to use eval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I'd ideally like to create a streamlined interface which requires the user to select one of three radio buttons such as shown here:

```
<form id="icon-type">
    <input type="radio" name="icon" value="apples" /> Apples
    <input type="radio" name="icon" value="oranges" /> Oranges
    <input type="radio" name="icon" value="graphes" /> Grapes
</form>
```

Using jQuery it's easy to determine which of the three have been selected:

```
var iconType = $('input[name=icon]:checked').val();
```

However, I need to convert the string assigned to iconType to an previously created object of the same name. I've read that `eval()` is the best way to do this, but have also encountered numerous warnings stating that `eval()` should never be used. However there seems to be no other way to perform this conversion. Thus my question: while I recognize that `eval()` can certainly be misused, is this a case where `eval()` is indeed the appropriate approach?

Thoughts much appreciated!

EDIT: @DVK, thanks! Still a bit lost though; suppose my objects look like this:

```
var apple = new GIcon(baseIcon);
apple.image = "http://localhost/images/apple.png";

var orange = new GIcon(baseIcon);
orange.image = "http://localhost/images/orange.png";
```

So I need to convert the value retrieved from the selected radio button into the appropriate object reference. How would I store these in a hash as you explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple strings like this, you can also simply store the matching objects in a hash, and access like this

`var obj = object_map[iconType];`

Comment: Thanks much for the response, I'm still a bit lost though. I've edited my original post in order to add a bit of code.

Comment: And the beauty of using a hash, is that you can populate it in a loop based on your sample code:

   `object_map[type] = new GIcon(baseIcon);
object_map[type].image = image_base_url+type+".png";`

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = window[iconType]
```

You can also link the object directly to the input.

```
$(function() {
    var form = $("#icon-type");
    form.get(0).iconTypeObject = new Apples();
    form.get(1).iconTypeObject = new Oranges();
    form.get(2).iconTypeObject = new Grapes();
});

var iconObject = $('input[name=icon]:checked')[0].iconTypeObject;
```

Comment: @Chaos - I thought OP said "previously created", not "new" object?

Comment: @DVK - Well I assume the objects were created in the jQuery ready function.